# Rails, RestClient pass binary font file

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rest-client

I'm trying to use restclient to do this CURL post

curl -v  -i -X POST  -H 'X-Api-Secret: ' -F font=@myraid.ttf APIURL

This is what I have so far

```
response = RestClient::Request.execute(
       :method => :post,
       :url => api_url,
       :headers => {:content_type => 'multipart/form-data', :accept => 'application/json', :X_Api_Secret => "xxxxxxxxx"}
    )
```

which works perfectly until I try to pass a file like this

```
response =RestClient::Request.execute(
       :method => :post,
       :url => api_url,
       :headers => {:content_type => 'multipart/form-data', :accept => 'application/json', :X_Api_Secret => "xxxxxxxxxx"},
       :upload => {
        :file => File.new(params[:custom_font][:font].path, 'rb')
      }
    )
```

It then seems to ignore my headers and I get a 403 error, I've also tried a regular rest-client post request like

response = RestClient.post api_url, { :X_Api_Secret => "xxxxxx"}

But again it breaks when I try to introduce the data file.

Any help, pointers or advice would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Ok after a couple of days of head banging, I ended up using unirest instead, after updating to the latest version it worked straight away.

```
response = Unirest.post api_key,
  headers:{
    "X-Api-Secret" => "xxxxx"
  },
  parameters:{
    "data" => "ccc"
  }
```